# Show that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ defined recurrence relation $a_0=25, a_{n+1}=2\sqrt{a_n}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Show that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ defined recurrence relation $a_0=25, a_{n+1}=2\sqrt{a_n}$ converges. I showed that it is bounded from below by $1$, but I'm struggling to show that the sequence is non-increasing. I tried induction, but the induction hypothesis is not helpful at all.

Comment: Try showing instead it's lower bounded by $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $a_1 = 10 < 25 = a_0$ so here we have our basic step.

For the inductive step, suppose $a_{n+1} < a_n$, we want $a_{n+2} < a_{n+1}$.

$a_{n+2} \stackrel{?}{<} a_{n+1}$ is equivalent to $2\sqrt{a_{n+1}} \stackrel{?}{<} 2\sqrt{a_n}$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Yes I can, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{4}=\left(\frac{a_n}{4}\right)^{\frac 12}$, therefore $\frac{a_n}{4} = \left(\frac{a_0}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^n}} = \left(\frac{25}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^n}} \to 1$, as $n \to +\infty$.

Comment: Nice use of that invariant.

Answer (score 2):

Letting
$b_n = \log(a_n)$,
this becomes,
taking logs,
$b_{n+1}
=\log(2)+b_n/2
=c+b_n/2
$
where $c = \log 2$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
b_{n+1}
&=c+\frac12 b_n\\
&=c+\frac12(c+\frac12 b_{n-1})\\
&=\frac32 c+\frac14 b_{n-1}\\
&=\frac32 c+\frac14 (c+\frac12 b_{n-2})\\
&=\frac74 c+\frac18 b_{n-2})\\
&...\\
&=(2-\frac1{2^k}) c+\frac1{2^{k+1}} b_{n-k})
\qquad\text{(easily proved by induction)}\\
&\to 2c\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$a_n
\to e^{2c}
=e^{2\log(2)}
=2^2
=4
$.

Note that this does not
depend on the initial condition.